# Execute stored procedure with vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure of searching data that works perfectly in SQL Server 2008.

My stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSearch] 
    @SurName NVarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  
        SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName, SI.StudAddress , 
        SI.BirthDay, SI.Gender, SI.Nationality, SI.BirthPlace,
        SI.TelNum, SI.SchoolWhereGraduated , 
        SI.DatesWhenGraduated, SI.SchoolLastAttended,
        SI.Note, SI.StudImage,
        PI.Father_FirstName, PI.Father_LastName,
        PI.Father_MI, PI.Father_Occupation, 
        PI.Father_TelNUm, PI.Mother_FirstName, PI.Mother_LastName,
        PI.Mother_MI, PI.Mother_Occupation, PI.Mother_TelNum,
        PI.Contact_FirstName, PI.Contact_LastName, PI.Contact_MI,
        PI.Contact_Mobile, PI.Contact_TelNum,
        SH.SchoolYear, SH.Levels, SH.Section, SH.DateEnrolled
    FROM 
        StudentInformation SI 
    JOIN 
        StudentHistory SH ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
    JOIN 
        ParentInformation PI ON PI.ParentID = SI.ParentID
    WHERE 
        SI.Surname Like '%'+ @Surname+'%'
END
```

My problem is when I execute it from vb.net, it does not return any data, and no error message whenever I click the search button.

Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

My vb.net code

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As New OpenFileDialog

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        cn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSearch", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", txtSearch.Text)
            dt.Clear()
            da.Fill(dt)
            dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 50
            dgv1.DataSource = dt
            For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
                If TypeOf dgv1.Columns(i) Is DataGridViewImageColumn Then
                    DirectCast(dgv1.Columns(i), DataGridViewImageColumn).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
                End If
            Next
        End Using
        cn.Close()
   End Sub
```

Comment: Have you ran this proc directly in sql with the value you are trying. It maybe one of the joins...

Comment: @codexer, yes i tested the procedure in sqlserver and it gives me the right result. but when it did not work in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
            cn.Open()

            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSearch", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", txtSearch.Text)
                cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure
                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 50
                dgv1.DataSource = dt
                For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
                    If TypeOf dgv1.Columns(i) Is DataGridViewImageColumn Then
                        DirectCast(dgv1.Columns(i), DataGridViewImageColumn).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
            cn.Close()
       End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

You can rewrite

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Try
    cn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("uspSearch", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", txtSearch.Text)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv1.DataSource = dt
Catch x As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
Finally
    cmd.Dispose()
    cn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: I try your suggestions but Still no respond with the code. I think the problem is in the vb.net code

Comment: But you have not associated your da with cmd. So how can you fill dt?

Comment: May i ask if this line is correct for searching ?  `code cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", txtSearch.Text) `code

Comment: Its correct, but where are you executing cmd and what is the relation between da and cmd?

Comment: @Hermal `code`Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter `code`

Comment: @DietherSilverious I added a sample code with update, change according to your need.

Comment: your second code works perfectly. When i put inside the search button `code` Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim dt As New DataTable() `code` It works like a charm. anyway i am just wondering why should i put that inside the search button when i already declared  that in my form after the PUBLIC CLASS FORMNAME?

Comment: It should work, might be some initialization problem

Answer (score 2):

You should inform the SqlCommand that you are setting the name of a stored procedure in its CommandText property

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSearch", cn)
        ' add this line'
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt = new DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        ....

    End Using
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

The default for the CommandType is Text, so it is expected that the string used for the command text is a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE etc... not the name of a StoredProcedure

Comment: I try your suggestions but still no response.Search button is not working.

Comment: Where do you build that variable da? Whithout proper connection to the command to execute it could do nothing or whatever was your previous command, answer updated

Comment: OK but the adapter to fill the table needs the command. Look at the updated answer. Here I use a local variable declared just when you need it and initialized with the proper SqlCommand

Comment: By the way, looking at the stored procedure code it seems that you have two parameters in use there (@surname and @search) but you pass just one. However this should result in an exception thrown when you call da.Fill.

Comment: i already edit the vb.net code to see the declaration of the variable and i delete the search variable in proc. Search variable is nothing to do with the store procedure because i write that as a comment. i just forgot to delete

Comment: thanks for commenting. The code given by Hemal fits according to my need.